# What is the difference between Owner and User (WindowsIdentity)?

Tags: .net, security, windows-identity

When getting the username and/or SID of the current user, what is the preferred method?

Is it using:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Owner
```

Or:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User
```

What is the difference between the two? This would be a great question for SuperUser.com, but alas, it's not live yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you usually want is the User.

Every security object in windows has permissions and owner. The user is also a security object so it has permissions and owner. The ownership means that the owner can change the permission on the user. And the permission (in case of the user object ) means things like delete the user, change group membership and such. And all of this is not intersting in most cases. So what you need is the 'User'.